# Uploading an image with filepicker.IO

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to use the Filepicker IO API to let users upload images.  I am trying to duplicate the steps shown in the "get started" video, but I am running into a road block.  The Filepicker opens fine, but it doesn't seem to be calling the javascript function (openFilePicker()) I have in the div (when the filepicker settings are set in the div, then it works).  Also, after I upload an image, I am not sure how to get the information so I can display it on another page (store it with php, etc..)  If you could help me out I would really appreciate it.  Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openFilePicker() {

        filepicker.setKey('MYKEYHERE');

        filepicker.pick({
                        mimetypes: ['image/*', 'text/plain'],
                        container: 'window',
                        services:['COMPUTER', 'FACEBOOK', 'GMAIL', 'PICASA', 'DROPBOX', 'INSTAGRAM', 'FLICKR'],
                        },
                        function(FPFile){
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(FPFile));

                        //UPLOAD COMPLETE
                        UpdateHTMLWithUploadedFile(FPFile.url);

                        },
                        function(FPError){
                        console.log(FPError.toString());
                        }
                        );

    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js"></script>


<div class="row margin" id='img-row'>
 <input id="filename" disabled="disabled" class="input-text file-input-value" type="text" style="width: 360px;" value=""/>
  <input name="img" data-fp-class="form-simple-action-btn filepicker_launcher" data-fp-button-text="Choose Image" data-fp-container="modal" type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="MYKEYHERE" id='campaign-img-input' onclick="javascript:openFilePicker()">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the documentation on the [filepicker.io widgets](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-pick) with that of the [filepicker.io javascript api](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#pick). If you'd like to bind to the onclick event of an object and use the `filepicker.pick` call directly, you should use a standard button rather than a filepicker input type, i.e.

```
<button onclick="javascript:openFilePicker()">Choose Image</button>
```